# I am Getting System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional in wcf and Web Api REST Web Services for the large data

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have created WCF and Web Api REST full web services. In this web services i am getting

[image: WCF _ERROR]

for Large data transmission.

**EX:**    I have 25 columns and 25000 rows of fetch query in this scenario some times data is coming and some time

[image: WCF_error]

this error is coming in both of them.
**My WCF Config. Like this**

[image]

So can anyone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try set in web config reader quoata for binding
defualt is small for large transmision

Details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325(v=vs.110).aspx

Example

```
<binding name="myLargeBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
</binding>
```

Then don't forget set this bindningConfiguration to endpoint(s)

```
<endpoint ....  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myLargeBinding" .... >
```

For your web.config it should be something like this.

I've created new binding configuration "RESTBinding" and set it to your endpoint.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"  />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="1048576"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="wcfTestHC.TestHC">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RESTBinding" contract="wcfTestHC.ITestHC"  />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp  helpEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="250" maxConcurrentInstances="75" maxConcurrentSessions="50"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="RESTBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>        
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EndpointBehavior" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="True" ordered ="True "/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>     
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>
  </switches>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="1073741824"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you still getting a error. Maybe problem is somewhere else.
Try insert these settings to your web.config. This will provide you a detailed logging and exceptions details for your service and there we will see what problem is. I've set a location for logs to c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog, plese change it if you want and I've edited a example of web.config with these settings - copy and paste ready :-)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>     
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>
  </switches>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Polacekpavwl, thanks for reply. actually i did't get the option like `maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"` on binding tag. i am using 4.5 framework. can you suggest me on this.

Comment: At your endpoint section <endpoint address="" .... > is missing bindingConfiguration element so endpoint doesn't know what configuration you want to set so everything is defualt. And another problem is that your endpoint has binding="webHttpBinding" (which is good for rest) but configration binding element is <wsHttpBinding>. If you past your configuration as text not as image I will correct it for you

Comment: Hi Polacekpavwl, thanks for reply. just check this link you will get the code (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/854390/I-am-Getting-System-Threading-Tasks-Task-ThrowIfEx) . suggest me on the same..

Comment: Hi Polacekpavwl, i followed your suggestions still i am get the same error what ever i mentioned on post... what i did wrong on  my config. or i missed anything on my config. file  ...  please suggest me on this...

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I've updated it with diagnostic settings. Change it please and call it again.

Comment: Hi Polacekpavel, I tried this.. how can identify the where the issue is.. because i am new from this.. So please suggest me on this..

Comment: When you add a diagnostics section to your web.config call web service again and open log ( in example is stored in c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog ). There you can see any exception in your code and any exception which throw WCF - more info abot tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx. Can you see something at log which throws exception?